# Percentage calculation of positive/negative values inside a list in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list that was converted from a pandas `DataFrame`:

```
[['2020.06.25 11:20:12', 'US500', 'sell', 1.0, 3047.3, '2020.06.25 11:21:32', 3051.4, 0.0, **-3.89**], ['2020.06.25 11:20:59', 'US500', 'sell', 1.0, 3049.8, '2020.06.25 11:21:33', 3051.6, 0.0, **-1.71**], ['2020.06.25 11:23:49', 'US500', 'sell', 1.0, 3051.6, '2020.06.25 11:25:32', 3049.7, 0.0, **1.8**]]
```

I wanted to calculate the percentage of times the number in bold is negative or positive for 'US500', that in the list can change with other strings like 'FB'.

So the output should look like:

US500: 60% positive, 40% negative
FB: 70% positive, 30% negative
etc.

I tried this:

```
ticker_list = df.values.tolist()
pos = [sum(y>=0 for y in x)  for x in zip(ticker_list)]
```

but I got an error

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

and it wouldn't give what I want anyway.

Update:

With the new code it is possible to get positive and negative %, but it tries to save it, it doesn't iterate through the loop but just prints one value:

```
   stocks = set([i[1] for i in ticker_list])
   worksheet.write_column(3,0,stocks)


   for s in stocks:
        result = [i[-1] for i in ticker_list if s in i]
        pos = (len([x for x in result if x > 0])/len(result))*100
        neg = [100 - pos]
        worksheet.write_column(3,1,pos)

        worksheet.write_column(3,1,pos)
```

just save 1 value as the output:

[image]

Comment: if you iterate the zip's output it gives the value as (list),(list) so on. Therefore when you do for y in x you are actually comparing the whole list to >=0 .  What you are trying to achieve here can be done through pandas more efficiently.

Comment: What is `worksheet`? Which library did you use? Please include a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You are writing over and over on the same column and row... `worksheet.write(3,1,pos)` please read how the write method of that object works.

Answer (score 4):

Recreating your dataframe from the given list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df)
                     0      1     2    3       4                    5       6    7     8
0  2020.06.25 11:20:12  US500  sell  1.0  3047.3  2020.06.25 11:21:32  3051.4  0.0 -3.89
1  2020.06.25 11:20:59  US500  sell  1.0  3049.8  2020.06.25 11:21:33  3051.6  0.0 -1.71
2  2020.06.25 11:23:49  US500  sell  1.0  3051.6  2020.06.25 11:25:32  3049.7  0.0  1.80
```

Use [`np.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) which returns an element wise indication of the **sign** of a number, then use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map `1` as positive and `-1` as negative, then use [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) on `s` along with aggregation functions `value_counts` and `count` to get the percentage:

```
s = np.sign(df[8]).map({1: 'Positive', -1: 'Negative'})
pct = s.groupby(df[1]).value_counts().div(s.groupby(df[1]).count()).mul(100)
```

**Details:**

```
print(s) 
0    Negative
1    Negative
2    Positive
Name: 8, dtype: object

print(pct)
1      8       
US500  Negative    66.666667
       Positive    33.333333
Name: 8, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Excellent use of `np.sign`. I have learned something today, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure where FB is, I assume you will have it in your list.
Also, I don't get why would you use `zip()` at all. Why would you make a list and not work on the DataFrame directly is also a mystery. Anyway, given your input (the initial list), the following code is enough.

```
data = [
    ['2020.06.25 11:20:12', 'US500', 'sell', 1.0, 3047.3, '2020.06.25 11:21:32', 3051.4, 0.0, -3.89],
    ['2020.06.25 11:20:59', 'US500', 'sell', 1.0, 3049.8, '2020.06.25 11:21:33', 3051.6, 0.0, -1.71],
    ['2020.06.25 11:23:49', 'US500', 'sell', 1.0, 3051.6, '2020.06.25 11:25:32', 3049.7, 0.0, 1.8]
]

us500 = [i[-1] for i in data if 'US500' in i]
pos = (len([x for x in us500 if x >= 0]) / len(us500)) * 100
neg = 100 - pos
print(pos, neg)
33.33333333333333 66.66666666666667
```

A more general ways would be:

```
data = [
    ['2020.06.25 11:20:12', 'US500', 'sell', 1.0, 3047.3, '2020.06.25 11:21:32', 3051.4, 0.0, -3.89],
    ['2020.06.25 11:20:59', 'US500', 'sell', 1.0, 3049.8, '2020.06.25 11:21:33', 3051.6, 0.0, -1.71],
    ['2020.06.25 11:23:49', 'US500', 'sell', 1.0, 3051.6, '2020.06.25 11:25:32', 3049.7, 0.0, 1.8],
    ['2020.06.25 11:20:12', 'FB', 'sell', 1.0, 3047.3, '2020.06.25 11:21:32', 3051.4, 0.0, -3.89],
    ['2020.06.25 11:20:59', 'FB', 'sell', 1.0, 3049.8, '2020.06.25 11:21:33', 3051.6, 0.0, 1.71],
    ['2020.06.25 11:23:49', 'FB', 'sell', 1.0, 3051.6, '2020.06.25 11:25:32', 3049.7, 0.0, 1.8]
]

stocks = set([i[1] for i in data])

for s in stocks:
    result = [i[-1] for i in data if s in i]
    pos = (len([x for x in result if x > 0])/len(result))*100
    neg = 100 - pos
    print(s, pos, neg)


US500 33.33333333333333 66.66666666666667
FB 66.66666666666666 33.33333333333334
```

Comment: thanks. The reason why I'm not using pandas is because I want to practice in Python. Yes, FB is also there. This code would be specific for US500. How to keep it general for US500, FB or other strings? Thanks.

Comment: @Steven I have added a more general version. The concept is the same.

Comment: @alec_djinn Nice answer, just a suggestion we can use dictionary to keep track of positive and negative values.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Sure, I have simply used `print()`, the OP can add it to a dict, append it to a list, or do whatever he wants with it. Unfortunately, the question didn't specify any preferred output type, looks like the OP just wanted to print something out.

Comment: @alec well, yes, I want to print the results in Excel

Comment: @Steven PRINT in Excel doesn't make sense; maybe you want to SAVE it as CSV or XLS. Please add all the requirements to your question. It is a bit vague as it is. Plus, as your goal is to learn Python, I would suggest you try it yourself, you have all the core logic in place already, just play with it, it's the best way to learn.

Comment: @alec yes, sorry I meant save it as xls. I just needed this step, so I didn't want to write the complete code and what I wanted to do with it. You're right, but sometimes I get stuck on something and can't find the right way to do it.

Comment: @alec_djinn I tried to save it as xls using worksheet.write_column(3,1,pos) but it gives an error that 'float' object is not iterable, although the loop works fine when you print it. How it can be?

Comment: @Steven That is a separate issue, you should post a new question and post the code you are using and the details of the error you are getting. I am not sure what library you are using. I would simply write the output to a CSV file, line by line.

Comment: @alec_djinn I actually updated my question for completeness, so that I can accept the final answer at the end.