# Calculation of percentage of negative and prices for a three year period pandas

Tags: python, pandas, percentage

```
Df = ['FY', 'DATE', 'TIME', 'PRICE']
```

I have several thousand values in each column. In the price column I have both negative and positive values. I want to calculate the percentage of negative values in the price columns for the FYs. That is, what is the percentage of negative values for TIME column by FY.

I have seperated the values by `np.where(['price'] < 0 , 1, 0])` and then used `groupby` to count the observations but confused about how to calculate the percentages.

| FINYEAR | QUARTER | MONTH | DATE | PRICE | Neg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 3 | 7 | 2016-07-01 00:30:00 | 292.91 | False |
| 2017 | 3 | 7 | 2016-07-01 01:00:00 | 112.63 | False |
| 2017 | 3 | 7 | 2016-07-01 01:30:00 | 75.52 | False |

Comment: Please show a sample of your dataframe.

Comment: _"That is, what is the percentage of negative values for TIME column by FY"_ - what do you mean by "for TIME"? A sample of your dataframe would be useful here.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) That applies to sample data as well.

Comment: Alright, will remove

Comment: Will you please also show a sample of your expected output?

Comment: I am confused about the methodology. Basically, I want to know the percentage of each value of negative price over three year period ( a new column for that ). if it makes sense

Comment: A basic sample of you dataframe is needed

Answer (score 0):

Check this Example:

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
 
# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 100], ['nick', -150], ['juli', -140]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'P&L'])

negative_values = (df[df['P&L']<0].count())
total_values = df.shape[0]
pct = round((negative_values/total_values)*100,2)
print(pct)

Output:

66.67
```

If you want to calculate pct of negative value but using groupby on specific column, check this ans: [Percentage calculation of positive/negative values inside a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63656190/percentage-calculation-of-positive-negative-values-inside-a-list-in-python)